# VSCode LaTeX Workshop - Use minted package?

Tags: minted

I am using the VSCode Extension LaTeX Workshop v8.4.2 in Docker with the `tianon/latex` image.
I am trying to use the minted package for some source code highlighting, however during compilation I'll get a build error:

[image]

I did some research an apparently there is a file where I can add the `--shell-escape` flag, I was not able to find that file tho.
Can someone guide me on how I can fix the error?
Or, alternatively, is there a better docker image that already has all these packages included, which might save me some headache?

**EDIT**: I got rid of the `--shell-escape` flag error by modifying the settings.json file as described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/432459/pygmentize-not-installed-error-on-visual-studio-code).
However I still can't seem to properly install pygmentize, the log still tells me it is not installed. 
I have it installed on my local machine, however I assume it has to be installed in the docker container somehow. How can I do this?

Comment: Apparently I got rid of the --shell-escape flag error by modifying the settings.json file. However I still have the pygmentize error.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Fixed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved it. First I created a custom docker image, based on `tianon/latex`, but with `pygmentize` installed.

Dockerfile:

```
FROM tianon/latex
LABEL description="Modded tianon"
RUN apt-get update -y && \
    apt-get install -y python-pygments && \
    rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/*
```

After building, I added that image in the LaTeX workshop. Then it worked fine.

**Note**: After changing the docker image from `latex/tianon` to my custom one, the `settings.json` file got reset, so I had to add the `--shell-execute` flag again, as described in the post linked above.